# Tizen Net bezel rotate event not triggered

Tags: .net, emulation, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Trying to begin development of **widget** for Galaxy Watch. Doing it in Visual Studio 2017. Using NET extension(based on Xamarin).... for debug using Tizen Emulator (Wearable 5.0).
I'm trying to handle **bezel rotate** event. Here is the simplest code :

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainPage : CirclePage,IRotaryEventReceiver
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Rotate(RotaryEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but my breakPoint inside of Rotate function is never triggered... 
If i put break point in construktor - it is yes triggered - so looks like environment is fine (compiled+deployed+running+attached...)
any Ideas whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't set a RotaryFocusObject property for the IRotaryEventReceiver. The RotaryEvent of IRotaryEventReceiver will not be called unless a RotaryFocusObject is set.

For more information, please read the API guide and consider adding the following lines to your Xaml file.
https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.CircularUI/guide/IRotaryEventReceiver.html

```
<w:CirclePage
  ...

  x:Name="MyCirclePage"
  RotaryFocusObject="{x:Reference MyCirclePage}">
```

Also the line breakpoints should work if you are debugging with Wearable 5.0 emulator on the VisualStudio. Here's a list of features currently supported by the debugger for Tizen 5.0.
https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg/wiki/Features